# Image Convolution and Boundaries

Tags: c++, c, arrays, matrix, convolution

I've been attempting at implementing the convolution algorithm onto a 1 dimensional array but needs to be represented as a 2D NxM matrix. After attempting to implement a method similar to this:

```
int kCenterX = kCol / 2;
int kCenterY = kRow / 2;

for(int i=0; i < mRow; ++i) {              // rows
    for(int j=0; j < mCol; ++j) {          // columns

        for(int m=0; m < kRow; ++m) {     // kernel rows
            int mm = kRow - 1 - m;      // row index of flipped kernel
            for(int n=0; n < kCol; ++n) { // kernel columns
                int nn = kCol - 1 - n;  // column index of flipped kernel

                // index of input signal, used for checking boundary
                int ii = i + (m - kCenterY);
                int jj = j + (n - kCenterX);

                // ignore input samples which are out of bound
                if( ii >= 0 && ii < mRow && jj >= 0 && jj < mCol )
                    o[i][j] += input[ii][jj] * kern[mm][n];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

source: http://www.songho.ca/dsp/convolution/convolution.html#convolution_2d

And given that the two matrices given are:

```
input = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,15,16};
// 1   2   3   4
// 5   6   7   8
// 9   10  11  12
// 13  14  15  16

sharpen_kernel = {0,-1,0,-1,5,-1,0,-1,0};
// 0  -1  0
// -1  5 -1
// 0  -1  0
```

The issue is the coder who developed it set that all values outside the edges are 0. So what method could I use to check when an element is on the edge of an array and then push out those values so they would get calculated with the kernel values. Essentially to represent the matrix as:

```
1    1   2   3   4   4
1   *1   2   3   4*   4
5   *5   6   7   8*   8
9   *9   10  11  12*  12
13  *13  14  15  16*  16
13   13  14  15  16  16
```

Comment: Additionally i'm also confused about the line:
 if( ii >= 0 && ii < mRow && jj >= 0 && jj < mCol )

It states that it skips input samples when out of bounds, but when you run it still calls for values at ii,jj (eg, -1,-1). How does the program still run if you're reading memory outside of the allocated section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated code

```
int kCenterX = kCol / 2;
int kCenterY = kRow / 2;

for(int i=0; i < mRow; ++i) {              // rows
    for(int j=0; j < mCol; ++j) {          // columns

        for(int m=0; m < kRow; ++m) {     // kernel rows
            int mm = kRow - 1 - m;      // row index of flipped kernel
            for(int n=0; n < kCol; ++n) { // kernel columns
                int nn = kCol - 1 - n;  // column index of flipped kernel

                // index of input signal, used for checking boundary
                int ii = i + (m - kCenterY);
                int jj = j + (n - kCenterX);

                if(ii < 0)
                    ii=ii+1;
                if(jj < 0)
                    jj=jj+1;
                if(ii >= mRow)
                    ii=ii-1;
                if(jj >= mCol)
                    jj=jj-1;    
                if( ii >= 0 && ii < mRow && jj >= 0 && jj < mCol )
                    o[i][j] += input[ii][jj] * kern[mm][n];

            }
        }
    }
}
```